# Can I pass an array argument with @selector for a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arguments, action, selector

I've a `UIButton` on which I want to add a target action which is stored into an `NSArray`.

I wants something like,

```
- (IBAction) myAction
{
    //Do Something
}

 //Add myAction to myArray
[myArray addObject:myAction]; 

 //Add target on myButton
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector([myArray objectAtIndex:0]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I am trying for it, but its show error messages like, `Expected Identifier` and `Expected ]`

Is it possible? Is there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `myArray` is an array of `NSStrings` that you want to use as selectors, then you can use `NSSelectorFromString`:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString([myArray objectAtIndex:0]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Or, if you want to store selectors in an `NSArray`, you have to wrap them in an `NSValue` because a `SEL` is not an Objective-C object:

```
NSValue* selCommandA = [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(handleCommandA:)];
NSValue* selCommandB = [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(handleCommandB:)];

NSArray *handlers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:selCommandA, selCommandB, nil ];

SEL mySelector = [[handlers objectAtIndex:0] pointerValue];
[myButton addTarget:self action:mySelector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can store the selector names as a string and then create a selector from those names. Example:

```
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"method1", @"method2", nil];
[myButton addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString([myArray objectAtIndex:0]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: And if you want to pass the button object to the method, just put : after method name (method1: etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting the selector into the array instead.

A `SEL` is a struct, so you need to convert it to an `NSValue` to store it in an array

```
[myArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&@selector(myAction) withObjCType:@encode(Selector)]];
```

And then you can just get the `NSValue` off the array, convert the value into a `SEL`, and use that as the action.

```
SEL selector;
[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] getValue:&selector];
[myButton addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

A selector is the name of a method (e.g. "`doSomething:`") inside an object or class and can not be an object itself.

If you want to pass an array, have that method get `myArray` as a instance variable, defined in the `.h` interface file or a `@property`.